# Encoded PDF file source to save file

Tags: php, pdf, encoding, base64

I have a source of PDF file base64 encoded.

This is source: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/Lz8Zyfq7

I want to save file with base64_decode. But I can not properly save the PDF file. Generated and decoded PDF file looks empty. It is not 0 KB.

```
$fileContent = base64_decode($base64EncodedSource);
$fileName = "temp.PDF";
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Length: '.strlen( $fileContent ));
        header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
        header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
        echo $fileContent;
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I generate this source inside a java app. In java app side is not corrupt. I can decode it and put in a file. I can open the file properly.

Comment: I miscopied before and deleted my previous comment. Yeah, it generates a PDF, just all white. Does the original PDF render something different which isn't a blank page?

Comment: @Ultimater yeah it's blank in PHP side. But in java app side it's not blank or empty. I could not understand difference.

Comment: I think you generated a base64 string for a blank PDF and thus your error is probably in the code which generated it in the first place. Try generating a new base64 string for the original PDF as your PHP code is fine if the base64 string were for a PDF that wasn't blank.

Comment: Try tossing `data:application/pdf;base64,` in front of it and loading it in your browser. Blank page: faulty PDF.

Comment: @Ultimater thank you for your answer. I try like this usage: `$fileContent = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'.$fileContent;` But my problem continues.

Comment: That isn't what I meant. I meant this isn't a PHP issue at all. Toss it directly in your browser's address bar as if it began with http and you'll see it's a blank PDF indeed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme